# Button Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to create a custom button shortcode, with multiple color and size options.  However, when I try to use the shortcode in my post it isn't showing up.

My Function

```
function btn($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => '#', 'color' => 'teal' , 'size' => 'large'), $atts));
   return '<a class="btn '.$size.'" href="'.$link.'" style="background:'.$color.';"><span>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span></a>';
}
```

How I am using the shortcode

```
[btn color="blue" size="large"]Button Text[/btn]
```

My CSS

```
/* Buttons */
.btn {background:#222 url(img/alert-overlay.png) repeat-x; display:inline-block; padding:5px 10px 6px; color:#fff!important; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; line-height:1; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; position:relative; cursor:pointer; -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); text-shadow:0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25)}
.btn:active{-webkit-transform:translateY(1px); -moz-transform:translateY(1px)}

/* Sizes ---------- */
.small { font-size: 11px; margin:10px 0 }
.medium { font-size: 13px; margin:10px 0 }
.large { font-size: 14px; padding: 8px 14px 9px; margin:10px 0 }

/* Colors ---------- */
.blue { background-color: #2daebf }
.red { background-color: #e33100 }
.magenta { background-color: #a9014b }
.orange { background-color: #ff5c00 }
.yellow { background-color:#ffb515 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
function btn($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => '#', 'color' => 'teal' , 'size' => 'large'), $atts));
   return '<a class="btn '.$size.'" href="'.$link.'" style="background:'.$color.';"><span>' . $content . '</span></a>';
}

add_shortcode('btn', 'btn');
?>
```